# How can I replace numbers in filenames with leading zero in bash?

Tags: linux, bash

There are similar questions about how to add numbers with leading zero etc. but in my case my filename has two numbers which is the number of chapter and the number of page. Both lack the leading zero, so they aren't sorted alphabetically. Using `rename` or any other method I want to convert files like these:

```
file_1_1.mp3  to file_01_01.mp3
file_1_12.mp3 to file_01_12.mp3
file_12_1.mp3 to file_12_01.mp3
...
```

I tried this:

```
rename 's/\d+/sprintf("%02d",$&)/e' *.mp3
```

but it just add leading zero to the chapter number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
rename -n 's/(\d+)_(\d+)\./sprintf("%02d_%02d.", $1, $2)/e' *.mp3
```

Remove `-n` switch when the output looks good for you

## Output

```
rename(file_1_12.mp3, file_01_12.mp3)
rename(file_1_1.mp3,  file_01_01.mp3)
rename(file_12_1.mp3, file_12_01.mp3)
```

[man rename](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/rename/file-rename.1p.en.html)

[image: warning] **There are other tools with the same name which may or may not be able to do this, so be careful.**

The rename command that is part of the `util-linux` package, won't.

If you run the following command (`GNU`)

```
$ rename
```

and you see `perlexpr`, then this seems to be the right tool.

If not, to make it the default (usually already the case) on `Debian` and derivative like `Ubuntu` :

```
$ sudo apt install rename
$ sudo update-alternatives --set rename /usr/bin/file-rename
```

---

For archlinux:

```
pacman -S perl-rename
```

---

For RedHat-family distros:

```
yum install prename
```

The 'prename' package is in the [EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) repository.

---

For Gentoo:

```
emerge dev-perl/rename
```

---

For *BSD:

```
pkg install gprename
```

or `p5-File-Rename`

---

For Mac users:

```
brew install rename
```

---

If you don't have this command with another distro, search your package manager to install it or [do it manually](https://metacpan.org/module/RMBARKER/File-Rename-0.20/rename.PL) (no deps...)

---

<sub><sup>This tool was originally written by Larry Wall, the Perl's dad.</sup></sub>

Answer (score 1):

This shell script works:

```sh
for file in *mp3
do
    new=$(echo "$file" | sed 's/_/_0/g; s/_0\([0-9][0-9]\)/_\1/g;');
    mv "$file" "$new";
done;
```

- Appends a `0` to each underscore found
- Removes that `0` if it resulted in at least digits in a row

Edit: added `g`lobal flag to the 2nd `s`ubstitute command, per comment by @PaulHodges

Comment: need a `g` modifier on the second `s///` also to make sure it gets them all across the name, yes?

Comment: @PaulHodges: Good catch.  Not an issue with the three files given in the question, but would be if the file contains multiple 2-digit sequences at the start, _e.g._, `file_12_12.mp3`.